# Is BigInteger-based Brainfuck Turing Complete?

Tags: computability, pl.programming-languages, turing-machines

All of the proofs of Turing-Completeness I've found for Brainfuck rely on its cells being fixed-width integers that wrap around upon over/underflow. The "parent language" [P''](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%E2%80%B2%E2%80%B2) on which Brainfuck is based is explicitly specified as having "increment/decrement this cell modulo m" instructions.

So is Brainfuck with arbitrary-sized integer cells (no wraparound) actually Turing Complete? If not, is there some proof that it is not? For example, can we compute bounds on the BigNum-Brainfuck Busy Beaver numbers?

Comment: [Counter machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter_machine) (with as little as 2 counters) are Turing complete. It should be straightforward to simulate these in Brainfuck with just a constant number of bigint cells.

Comment: The Esolangs WIki has a section on their brainfuck page explaining variants that are known to be Turing complete inculding the one discussed on this question: https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck#Computational_class